# Various Proofs for Hodge Decomposition Theorem

Tags: homology-cohomology, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

This is the version I am referring it to:
$H^{k}_{DR}(X,\mathbb{C})=\bigoplus _{p+q=k}H^{p,q}_{DR}(X)$,where X is a Kahler manifold and $H^{k}_{DR}(X,\mathbb{C})=\dfrac{closed~forms}{exact~forms}$ in $\Omega^{k}(X)$.
This a very deep theorem and proofs for it are not readily available (ex. Wikipedia) like for other theorems. So this can be at least one place where we can find various proofs for it.

Comment: Dear Tomas, Are you looking for online sources.  Presumably Voisin's book on Hodge theory gives a proof, and there is a proof in Griffiths and Harris.  Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Here is one:
http://dspace.library.uu.nl/handle/1874/283345

The Hodge Decomposition Theorem
on Compact Kahler Manifolds